# Can GRUB font size be customised?

Tags: fonts, grub2, framebuffer

I would like to reduce the size of the font of GRUB boot loader. Is it possible and so how?

Answer (score 65):

After some research based on the answers of @fpmurphy and @hesse, also based on a comprehensive thread at [ubuntuforums](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1542338) and on [Fedora Wiki](http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Features/Grub2), I found out how to reduce the font size of GRUB2.

1. Choose a font, in this example I chose *DejaVuSansMono.ttf*
2. Convert the font in a format GRUB understands:
   `sudo grub2-mkfont -s 14 -o /boot/grub2/DejaVuSansMono.pf2 /usr/share/fonts/dejavu/DejaVuSansMono.ttf`
3. Edit the */etc/default/grub* file adding a line:
   `GRUB_FONT=/boot/grub2/DejaVuSansMono.pf2`
4. Update GRUB configuration with:

   - BIOS: `sudo grub2-mkconfig -o /boot/grub2/grub.cfg`
   - EFI: `sudo grub2-mkconfig -o /boot/efi/EFI/{distro}/grub.cfg # distro on RHEL8 is {'redhat'}`
5. reboot.

The resolution of GRUB display may also affect the size of the font, more on resolution etc. on the ubuntuforums link above.

Comment: On UEFI system one would use `grub2-mkconfig -o /boot/efi/EFI/centos/grub.cfg`

Comment: On Linux Mint 20 the command is `grub-mkfont`. On my systems, the use of DejaVuSansMono leads to "broken" vertical lines in the box around the boot menu, probably because the vertical box drawing characters are 1 pixel too short. On Mint 20 the only pre-installed font that did it correctly was "FreeMono.ttf"
`sudo grub-mkfont -s 24 -o /boot/grub/FreeMono.pf2 /usr/share/fonts/truetype/freefont/FreeMono.ttf`

Comment: @drfumanchu thanks, the same works for Ubuntu 20.04, (along with changing any `grub2` references to `grub`).  Also, /etc/default/grub advises to run `update-grub`, which calls `grub-mkconfig`, and (I'm hoping) does the right thing with regards to EFI.

Comment: To make the font in Fedora 34, use `sudo grub2-mkfont -s 20 -o /boot/grub2/DejaVuSansMono.pf2 /usr/share/fonts/dejavu-sans-mono-fonts/DejaVuSansMono.ttf`
To update GRUB on Fedora 34 use `sudo grub2-mkconfig -o /etc/grub2-efi.cfg`

Comment: I am trying to use the breeze theme. It already contains fonts as small as 12, so no need to run grub-mkfont, but it just WON'T PICK THEM UP, even if I change ALL fonts to size 12 in theme.txt. It just picks some hardcoded value.

Comment: This worked perfectly for me... until recently. It seems that a security fix to grub means that unsigned fonts are ignored. See https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=2144113 and https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/grub-devel/2022-11/msg00155.html

Comment: `sudo /usr/bin/grub-mkfont -s 16 -o /boot/grub/DejaVuSansMono.pf2 /usr/share/fonts/truetype/dejavu/DejaVuSansMono.ttf` for Linux Mint 21. Note that Grub2 in general now is just referenced as `grub`.

Comment: As @DavidRobertson mentionned, on Ubuntu 22.04 LTS I had this issue where it stopped working after a grub update (current version on 22.04 is `2.06-2ubuntu7.1`). The error message is `error: prohibited by secure boot policy` if we try the `loadfont` command. As in https://forums.debian.net/viewtopic.php?t=153356 somebody said there's a fixed version in debian 11.6, I tried leaving LTS and updating to 23.04 to get grub `2.06-2ubuntu16` but to no avail. Has anybody found a working solution?

Comment: ℹ️ **For pixel perfect**: Use `--verbose` to see the default size, then select a `--size` which is a multiple of that.

Answer (score 9):

In Debian/Ubuntu you can change the default GRUB resolution, thereby resulting in larger fonts on the GRUB menu:

1. Make a backup: `sudo cp -a /etc/default/grub /etc/default/grub.bak`
2. Open the configuration: `sudo $EDITOR /etc/default/grub`
3. Edit `GRUB_GFXMODE` entry to suit your resolution e.g. 800x600
4. `sudo update-grub`
5. Reboot; GRUB will display in the mode you set.

Answer (score 6):

Yes, both the font and the font size can be customised.  See the grub-mkfont utility.  Bitmap (.pf2) and Truetype (.ttf) fonts are supported.

Just do an Internet search on grub-mkfont and you will quickly come across a number of examples of the necessary steps.

Comment: Nice indeed I found [this documentation](http://myunster.com/blog/server-administration/18.html) but somehow I need to `update-grub`, which command I don't seem to have on Fedora 16 (?).

Comment: OK, I see [elsewhere](http://ask.fedoraproject.org/question/136/how-to-update-grub2-on-fedora-16) the equivalent of update-grub is `grub2-mkconfig -o /boot/grub2/grub.cfg`.

Answer (score 4):

I whipped up a little script to automatically scale font size to monitor/screen width.

```
SCREEN_WIDTH=$(xdpyinfo | grep dimensions | cut -d ':' -f 2 | cut -d 'x' -f 1)
FONT_SIZE=$((${SCREEN_WIDTH} / 80))
sudo grub-mkfont -s ${FONT_SIZE} -o /boot/grub/DejaVuSansMono.pf2 /usr/share/fonts/truetype/dejavu/DejaVuSansMono.ttf
printf "\nGRUB_FONT=/boot/grub/DejaVuSansMono.pf2" | sudo tee -a /etc/default/grub
sudo grub-mkconfig -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg
```

A few caveats

- This font is different from the default one
- On old systems you might need `grub2` instead of `grub`
- Doesn't consider multi-monitor setups

Enjoy!

Comment: I love it, I did change your 80 to 120

Answer (score 3):

If you are looking for a simpler GUI alternative, you can use [Grub Customiser](https://launchpad.net/~danielrichter2007/+archive/ubuntu/grub-customizer) to change the font size, colors and background of GRUB.