# How to fix mistake in grub.cfg from LiveCD?

Tags: fedora, grub2, livecd

[Playing around with the GRUB2 configuration](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/31672/can-grub-font-size-be-customised), I did something wrong, which caused the system to fail booting.

I would like to fix the issue by re-editing the GRUB configuration file using Fedora 16 LiveCD.

I proceeded as follow:

- mount my system partition [OK]
- become super user         [OK]
- sudo gedit the /etc/default/grub to restore it as it was prior [OK]
  (Somehow I had to "sudo" although I already was super-user, that's confusing).
- sudo grub2-mkconfig -o /media/MYPARTITION/boot/grub2/grub.cfg

The last step however returned the file system is read only. So I failed to restore the configuration of GRUB2 :(

How should I proceed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't even need a livecd; you can correct it within grub.  You can press `e` at the grub menu to edit the entry and fix whatever you broke, then `ctrl-x` to boot the corrected entry.  Once the system is up and running, fix your cfg file permanently.

Doing it that way from the live cd, you need to not mount the partition read only.  If you didn't mount it read only, then it must have an error that caused it to switch to read only, so you should fsck it before mounting.