# Grub with retina displays (high resolution)

Tags: grub2

I currently use Ubuntu on my macbook pro with grub. My macbook has a retina display with 2560x1600 resolution. The grub startup screen font is so tiny that it is barely readable.

How can I make grub appear in an eye-friendly way with this setup? Just passing on a gfx mode like `GRUB_GFXMODE=640x480` does not have any effect?

Thanks for a solution.

Comment: after edit `GRUB_GFXMODE` , you have to type: `sudo update-grub` then reboot your system

http://askubuntu.com/questions/54067/how-do-i-safely-change-grub2-screen-resolution

Comment: I did update grub (even if I did not explicitely mention it). The problem is that the configuration has no effect. It looks like grub can only deal with the native resolution or at least I have not figured out how to make it work with a different resolution.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Since there seems no way to use a different resolution with this hardware, the solution is to increase the font size as described here: [Can GRUB font size be customised?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/31672/can-grub-font-size-be-customised)

Which works perfectly.

Comment: I found that changing `GRUB_GFXMODE` as per [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/54067/how-do-i-safely-change-grub2-screen-resolution#54068) worked fine for me so I didn't need to change the grub font. I did change the TTY console font to make it readable during boot using `sudo dpkg-reconfigure console-setup` and selecting terminus 16x32 for the font. (Ubuntu 18.04, Dell XPS 15, 4k)