# can't control font size on grub screen

Tags: linux, grub, video

I can't control the font size on the grub screen. For example, if I do:

```
grub set gfxmode=1024x768x32
```

I get no change in the font size, and it remains tiny. Why is this?

There is much on the internet about changing font size by editing /etc/default/grub and doing 'update-grub' and similar, but there is nothing about doing it on-the-fly right in the grub terminal.

I'm running Ubuntu 20.04 on a Lenovo t400.

Thanks for reading this. Happy holidays!

Comment: Relating https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/31672/117549

Answer (score 0):

I did updates to `grub.cfg` via editing `/etc/default/grub`, but they didn't work. Finally, I found out what video card was on the machine with `sudo lshw -c video` which indicated AMD.

Suspecting that the drivers had never been installed, I used a procedure given at [How To Install AMD Radeon Driver on Ubuntu 20.04 LTS](https://idroot.us/install-amd-radeon-driver-ubuntu-20-04/). I used the second procedure, which has the heading *Install AMD Radeon Driver using PPA third-party repository*:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:oibaf/graphics-drivers
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade
```

Indeed, the drivers had not been installed.

Following the procedure made the graphics perfect. I now have an Ubuntu 20.04 bootable USB (full install) which happily boots on my machine at work and liberates me from the horrors of Windows. I created the bootable on my Linux machine at home.

Comment: There only seems to be one procedure listed on the page that you link to, which has two steps. If you could [edit] your answer to actually include the steps that you followed, with the commands, then that would be more helpful. As it stands your answer is a bit of a link only answer, and if/when the [link dies](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Link_rot), your answer won't be as useful as it could have been. I have suggested an appropriate edit.

Comment: This is about graphics resolution, not about font size.

Answer (score -1):

According to [arunk's answer to
"Can GRUB font size be customised?"](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/344813):

Follow these instructions:

> 1. Make a backup: `sudo cp -a /etc/default/grub /etc/default/grub.bak`
> 2. Open the configuration: `sudo $EDITOR /etc/default/grub`
> 3. Edit `GRUB_GFXMODE` entry to suit your resolution e.g. 800x600
> 4. `sudo update-grub`
> 5. Reboot; GRUB will display in the mode you set.

Comment: This is about graphics resolution, not about font size.