# GRUB menu text and text on shutdown is very small

Tags: alma-linux

I’ve installed AlmaLinux 8.6 on a Dell XPS 15 7590.

The GRUB menu text and the text that appears when shutting down is very small I can barely read it. How can I fix this issue with the small text?

`hwinfo --framebuffer` displays nothing. Both `vbeinfo` and `videoinfo` in grub does not work and I get the error message '*can't find commmand*'. I have tried installing `915resolution` but when I run the command `find / -name 915*`, nothing is found except for the tarball itself and the extracted file/folder. Running `915resolution` in the grub menu also results in the error '*can't find command*'.

I have tried all sorts of resolution instead but nothing changes. This is the /etc/default/grub file:

```
GRUB_TIMEOUT=5
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR="$(sed 's, release .*$,,g' /etc/system-release)"
GRUB_DEFAULT=saved
GRUB_DISABLE_SUBMENU=true
GRUB_TERMINAL_INPUT="console"
GRUB_TERMINAL_OUTPUT="gfxterm"
GRUB_GFXMODE="1920x1080x32"
GRUB_GFXPAYLOAD="keep"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="crashkernel=auto resume=/dev/mapper/almalinux-swap rd.lvm.lv=almalinux/root rd.lvm.lv=almalinux/swap rhgb quiet"
GRUB_DISABLE_RECOVERY="true"
GRUB_ENABLE_BLSCFG=true
```

I run the `grub2-mkconfig -o /boot/efi/EFI/almalinux/grub.cfg` after and reboot but nothing changes.

I have tried changing fonts also as suggested in this article: [Can GRUB font size be customised?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/31672/can-grub-font-size-be-customised). Nothing changes when I do the exact same thing in the article.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can GRUB font size be customised?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/31672/can-grub-font-size-be-customised) https://vietlq.github.io/2019/09/22/make-grub-font-size-bigger/ https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/GRUB/Tips_and_tricks#Setting_the_framebuffer_resolution

Comment: I've tried that and it doesn't work. It's not just the GRUB menu that is small, the text that appears when shutting down is also small.

Comment: It seems I needed both the ```GRUB_TERMINAL_OUTPUT="gfxterm"``` and ```GRUB_FONT=/boot/grub2/DejaVuSansMono.pf2``` to get it to work. Now I need to fix the text that appears when shutting down.

Comment: The text you see when you're shutting down is the Linux console, **not** GRUB. To change its fonts https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Linux_console#Fonts