# How to change Grub's font size when in terminal mode?

Tags: linux, grub

I want to run GRUB in console mode instead of graphical mode on a 4K screen. That is, have the following in `/etc/default/grub`:

```
GRUB_TERMINAL=console
```

When I do this, the font is extremely small. `GRUB_GFXMODE` does not change the resolution because I am in console mode, not graphical mode.

What is the right way to change the font and/or resolution so that the text is readable?

Comment: Did you try loading larger font? [https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/31672/can-grub-font-size-be-customised](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/31672/can-grub-font-size-be-customised)?

Comment: Also:https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MaintenanceFreeCustomGrub2Screen &  https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1542338

Comment: @davidt930 That's it. `GRUB_FONT`. Thanks.